# Data sorting in query

Tags: sql-server-2005, sorting

I work with SQL Server 2005. I have a table in which FK: two columns (`book number, bookshelf number`). A PK = FK + `Datetime` column. And also I have the column of value. I want to create query, which sort the data as follows.

I have this data set:

```
BookNumber   BookshelfNumber          DateTime          Value
    0              0             12.01.2012 14:40:42      4
    0              0             12.01.2012 14:45:42      5
    0              0             12.01.2012 14:48:42      9
    0              1             12.01.2012 14:38:42      1
    0              1             12.01.2012 14:42:42      4
    0              1             12.01.2012 14:48:42      1
    1              1             12.01.2012 14:38:42      5
    1              1             12.01.2012 14:48:42      7
    1              1             12.01.2012 14:58:42      4
```

After query I want this result:

```
BookNumber   BookshelfNumber          DateTime          Value
    0              0             12.01.2012 14:40:42      4
    0              1             12.01.2012 14:38:42      1
    1              1             12.01.2012 14:38:42      5
```

Comment: Can you **describe** in English words what it is you're trying to query for?? E.g. given `BookNumber=0/BookshelfNumber=0` - why do you want to select the `Value = 4` row (and not another one??) Just seeing the desired output leaves us **guessing** (at best!) as to what it is you want....

Comment: @marc_s it seems it's a group by BookNumber and BookShelfNumber and giving the rows with the min Datetime && min Value

Comment: @aF.: that's a guess - probably correct - but the person asking should **SPECIFY** those things and not leave us guessing.....

Comment: @marc_s yep, u'r right about that!

Comment: @aF - going from the examples, it can't be the min `Value`. That would be 4 for BookNumber/BookshelfNumber 1/1.

Comment: @Lieven yes you are right, the min ROW_NUMBER then. No other possibility :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to add a number to your dataset that

- restarts numbering by each change in `Booknumber & BookshelfNumber` (`PARTITION BY`)
- Numbers the result from oldest to newest `datetime` (`ORDER BY`)

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          SELECT  BookNumber
                  , BookShelfNumber
                  , DateTime
                  , Value
                  , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY BookNumber, BookshelNumber ORDER BY DateTime)
          FROM    Books
        ) b
WHERE   rn = 1
```